# How can I display a custom field from all posts and order them individually from their parent post

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I have a post_type of 'interview' and within it is a repeater field 'interview' and sub_fields 'question' and 'answer'.  I would like to display all questions and answers from all interviews and orderby question, perhaps alphabetically.  So that on the actual page you see different answers from the same question.

Right now I am able to list all questions and answers but any attempt I make at orderby just orders them by question within the post and not over all.

What I want:

- Q1 from Post 1
- A1 from Post 1
- Q1 from Post 2
- A1 from Post 2
- Q2 from Post 1
- A2 from Post 1
- Q2 from Post 2
- A2 from Post 2

What I am getting:

- Q1 from Post 1
- A1 from Post 1
- Q2 from Post 1
- A2 from Post 1
- Q1 from Post 2
- A1 from Post 2
- Q2 from Post 2
- A2 from Post 2

I am using wp_query with args for post_type but it just seems that I'm actually returning just a list of all posts not a list of all custom fields because they stay grouped together by post.

```
 <?php 
    
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_type' => 'interview',
      'orderby' => 'question',
      'order' => 'DESC'
  ); 

    $answer_query = new WP_Query($args);    ?>
  <?php
    while ($answer_query->have_posts()): $answer_query->the_post();
    if( have_rows('interview') ):
      while( have_rows ('interview') ): the_row();
        // Questions and Answers
          if( get_sub_field('question')){
            $question = get_sub_field('question');
          }
          if( get_sub_field('answer')){
            $answer = get_sub_field('answer');
          }
          if( get_sub_field('qaid')){
            $qaid = get_sub_field('qaid');
          }
    echo '<div class="question_container">';
    echo '<div class="question"><h3>' . $question . '</h3></div>';
    echo '<div class="answer">' . $answer . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    endwhile; 
    endif;
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Comment: Querying by custom fields is expensive, meaning slow and potentially can cause significant performance issues. It would be wiser to rethink the setup - perhaps you could find a way to use taxonomies instead, as these are much faster.